# thread pool in constructor of C++ class is getting killed

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, boost-asio, threadpool

I have the following code which is creating thread pool in the constructor of the class. Threads got created and exited immediately.
Please help.

```
class ThreadPool {
public:
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    boost::thread_group threads;
    ThreadPool();
    void call();
    void calling(); 
};

ThreadPool::ThreadPool() {
    /* Create thread-pool now */
    size_t numThreads = boost::thread::hardware_concurrency();
    boost::asio::io_service::work work(io_service);
    for(size_t t = 0; t < numThreads; t++) {
        threads.create_thread(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &io_service));
    }
}

void ThreadPool::call() {
    std::cout << "Hi i'm thread no " << boost::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;
};

void ThreadPool::calling() {
    sleep(1); 
    io_service.post(boost::bind(&ThreadPool::call, this));
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   ThreadPool pool;
   for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    pool.calling();
   }
   pool.threads.join_all();
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: And you get no output ?

Comment: @Marco, no output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**boost::asio::io_service::work work** must be a member of the class, so it does not get destroyed.

```
class ThreadPool {
public:
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    boost::thread_group threads;
    boost::asio::io_service::work *work;
    ThreadPool();
    void call();
    void calling(); 
    void stop() { delete work; }
};

ThreadPool::ThreadPool() :  work(new boost::asio::io_service::work(io_service)) {
    /* Create thread-pool now */
    size_t numThreads = boost::thread::hardware_concurrency();
    for(size_t t = 0; t < numThreads; t++) {
        threads.create_thread(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &io_service));
    }
}

void ThreadPool::call() {
    std::cout << "Hi i'm thread no " << boost::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;
};

void ThreadPool::calling() {
    Sleep(1000); 
    io_service.post(boost::bind(&ThreadPool::call, this));
}

int main()
{
   ThreadPool pool;
   for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    pool.calling();
   }
   pool.stop();
   pool.threads.join_all();
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work ? In the code posted you are creating a work object inside constructor and it gets destroyed once the constructor is finished leaving the io_service with nothing to run.

Comment: I did a silly mistake that's why it was not working for me.. yap it worked !! Thank you !!

Comment: Your example has a memory leak; you don't `delete` the `work` object.

Comment: The complete example does not have a leak, since it calls stop(). But you are right that the destructor of ThreadPool should clean up better.